# How to change 71 x 12 cell array with tables to 1 x 71 cell array with table

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I use this code to change my `1 x 71` cell array to split into a `71 x 12` cell array. I do what I want with split cell and I want to back in `1 x 71` cell array, But I don't know how?

Here is the  code that I use for change `1 x 71` to `71 x 12` please help me reverse it:

```
Cmo = cell(numel(C),12);  
for i = 1:numel(C)
    Cmo(i,:) = arrayfun(@(m){C{i}(month(C{i}.date) == m, :)},1:12);
end
```

Comment: Why do you use `arrafun` here? It seems oddly complicated. Try a more cleaner implementation first -- in particular as you are new to Matlab

Comment: All of these conversions to your data seem suspect. Why do you think you need to do this? As with your previous question, it seems that all of your requirements could be satisfied by just leaving the data alone and using subscripting. Please give a minimal example of what you're trying to achieve so that we can give a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape` for both (but it maintains the number of elements, so it must be divisible without remainder):

```
C = cell(1,72);
% 1x72 => 12x6
C = reshape(C,12,length(C)/12);
% 12x6 => 1x72
C = reshape(C,size(C,2)*12,1);
```

This does not work for your case since you only have 71 entries. So you will have to do looping or extend your matrix fist and then use reshape

```
Num = ceil(length(C)/12)*12-length(C);
% assuming that C is an array (1x??)
C = [C,cell(1,Num)]
```